# What is the easy way to make method from function in Go?

Tags: go

It's quite trivial to get function from method using method expression

```
func (t T) Foo(){}
Foo := T.Foo       //yelds a function with signature Foo(t T)
```

Now suppose I already have

```
func Foo(t T)
```

can I get method `T.Foo()` without rewriting, or at least easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming T is a struct, you could:

```
func (t T) Foo() {
    Foo(t)
}
```

Comment: But why  necessarily struct?

Comment: `T` doesn't need to be a struct, just any type declared in the package.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the function `Foo(t T)`, for example for backwards-compatibility, you can simply define a struct method that calls the already-existing function:

```
type T struct {
    // ...
}

func Foo(t T) {
    // ...
}

// Define new method that just calls the Foo function
func (t T) Foo() {
    Foo(t)
}
```

Alternatively, you can easily change the function signature from `func Foo(t T)` to `func (t T) Foo()`. As long as you do not change the name of `t`, you will not have to rewrite the function itself any further.

Comment: Yes I see and totally agree. Are you sure there are no another way? Can we wait a bit for miracle answer?

Comment: IMHO there's no better solution.

Comment: Daniele D Nothing wrong. Just having so clear and concise Foo := T.Foo I wonder the same in opposite direction, which case is more frequent in practice. Semantically and technically operations looks symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out the best way to do this:

```
func (t T) Foo() { Foo(t) }
```

But if you for some reason need to do this at runtime, you can do something like this:

```
func (t *T) SetFoo(foo func(T)) {
    t.foo = foo
}

func (t T) CallFoo() {
    t.foo(t)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/A3G-V0moyH.

This is obviously not something you would normally do. Unless there is a reason, I'd suggest sticking with methods and functions as they are.

Comment: that's so ugly but still a nice idea